# Place Image center in Paragraph using CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I place a image in the center of a Paragraph and let the text wrap/break of the image. Without taking help of JS.

Something like this, here we have two paragraphs,  I need this with one paragraph with some text on top as well.

[image]

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/float-center/ has you covered - right down to the cat image...  But be warned it's not exactly dynamic - the image has to have known dimensions for this version to work.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/float-center/

Comment: @ryantdecker yes, That is why I am asking if I can do this with a single paragraph?

Comment: Seems like you want something more like CSS Shapes: http://alistapart.com/article/css-shapes-101 but that still only wraps one side as far as I know, and it's not widely supported.  You could split your text into span's inside the <p>, but I assume that will yeild the same issue you're trying to solve by not having 2 <p> elements